# Update mySql based specific onChange

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a page that present a big table in my SQL DB, and every cell is an HTML input.
The goal is to make a editable sql table that update my SQL DB based on changed in specific cell in big table form.
I tought about making a script that trigger a JS function when a cell-change occurs, that update the specific change.
Is it possible?
Any other idea?

This is a draft of my idea. The issue is the While loop that present the table

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#testnum').on('change', 'input', function(){
          $.post("getter.php",{###Don't know what to put here###);
    });
 });
  </script>


 <?php
    while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
         echo "<tr>
         <td onchange='changeit(fin)'>
         <div name='fin' style='display:none;'> ".$res['first'] ."</div>
         <input type='int' value=".$res['first'].">
        </td>
        <td onchange='changeit(sta)'>
            <div name='sta' style='display:none;'>".$res['second']."</div>
            <input type='int' value=".$res['second'].">
            </td>
            <td>";
    ?>
```

### EDIT

---

For example - how can I pass David's ID if I change his city?
(This table printed with WHILE statement)

```
ID    name     city
-------------------
1     David    NY
--------------------
2     John     LA
-------------------
3     Adam     NJ
```

if I change David's city to "London" for example I want to send 3 things:

1) The ID - so I know which specific row. (in this case - "1")

2) The column name - so I can know which column has changed. (in this case - "city")

3) The data after change - so I know what to update. (in this case - "London")

Comment: You'll need to send some data in the $.post, check this https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ . And which is the query of the result, is well written? Returns data? In the post callback, you can put something like $('#somediv').html(data);

Comment: Yeah I know.. The issue is that I want to change for example David name but if I send the new name how can I know which row to change? I want to send the ID but it in other cell.

Comment: I'll need to check but maybe, you can use a class for each row, like <td class="name-row"> and then use the $(this) operator to change only the affected row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use something similar to this, you'll need to adapt it to your code and needs.

HTML FILE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Table Check</title>
</head>

<body>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="col id"><input class="txtdata" name="id" value="1"></td>
      <td class="col name"><input class="txtdata" name="name" value="Jhon"></td>
      <td class="col city"><input class="txtdata" name="city" value="NY"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="col id"><input class="txtdata" name="id" value="2"></td>
      <td class="col name"><input class="txtdata" name="name" value="Jane"></td>
      <td class="col city"><input class="txtdata" name="city" value="LA"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'></script>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.txtdata').on('change', function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent('.col').parent('.row');
    var id = $(parent).find('.id').find('input').val();
    var name = $(parent).find('.name').find('input').val();
    var city = $(parent).find('.city').find('input').val();
    var attribChanged = $(this).attr('name');
    data = {id: id, name: name, city: city, attribChanged: attribChanged};
    $.post('getter.php', data, function(data){
      $(parent).html(data);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

PHP FILE:

```
<?php 
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] . '(mod)';
$id = $_REQUEST['id'] . '(mod)';
$city = $_REQUEST['city'] . '(mod)'; 
echo '<td class="id"><input class="txtdata" name="id" value="'.$id.'"></td>
      <td class="name"><input class="txtdata" name="name" value="'.$name.'"></td>
      <td class="city"><input class="txtdata" name="city" value="'.$city.'"></td>';
?>
```

Comment: I tried this now...doesn't work... Read the edit I made - this is what you tought I ment?

Comment: Ok so you need to send the ID of the row to change it in the DB too, and update the table with the new name. Basically reflect in the DB any change you do to the table. is that what you want?

Comment: precisely, if I change David's city to "London" for example I want to send 3 things: 1) The ID - so I know which specific row. (in this case - "1")  2) The column name - so I can know which column has changed. (in this case - "city") 3) The data after change - so I know what to update. (in this case - "London")

Comment: Hi check the answer, I've just updated it. I think it's what you need, but you'll have to adapt it to your code. Now is sending the ID, Name and City.

Comment: Now sends the attribute which has been changed in an extra parameter "attribChanged"

Comment: I'm checking it out right now with my code. I'll let you know when I finish, but It's looking good by far! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PHP file:

```
<?php
  echo '<table>';
  while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>$res['id']</td>';
      echo '<td onchange="changeit($res['id'], \'name\', this)"><input type="text" value="$res['name']"/></td>';
      echo '<td onchange="changeit($res['id'], \'city\', this)"><input type="text" value="$res['city']"/></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';
```

Jquery:

```
function changeit(id, field, element){
  var newVal = element.find('input').val();
  $.post("getter.php",{
    "id": id,
    "field": field,
    "newVal": newVal
  }, function(result){
     if(result == 'success'){
       alert('id: '+ id);
       alert('column: '+ field);
       alert('what change: '+ newVal);
     }
  });
}
```

PHP file `getter.php`:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$field = $_POST['field'];
$newVal = $_POST['newVal'];
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET $field = $newVal WHERE id = $id");
if($sql) echo 'success'; else echo '0';
```

Hope helpful for you.